# JIRA and gitlab CI integration

Tags: containers, jira

How would one trigger a Gitlab CI pipeline when a JIRA ticket is created? One of the fields in the Jira ticket will be for the name of a container image and it needs to be passed to the pipeline. The CI pipeline will when scan the image and attach the report to the ticket.

Comment: You can create a webhook in jira, that runs whenever a JIRA Issue is created (or whatever action you want to execute), if you are using Jira cloud, go to Project settings => automations. and create a new automation.